# display multiple event with difference color using Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, xslt

I want to display calendar based on 
"trainingrequestajax.php?dowhat=getapprovetraining" and "trainingrequestajax.php?dowhat=getavailabletraining" with difference color. Anyone can help me how to use events or eventSources to solve this problems? 
I use this code to display as one event, i want to add more event data from "trainingrequestajax.php?dowhat=getavailabletraining" and display it with different color.

```
<link href='/ock/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='/ock/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='/ock/scripts/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/ock/scripts/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='/ock/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
$k(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $k('#calendarview').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: "trainingrequestajax.php?dowhat=getapprovetraining",
        eventColor: 'blue'


    });



});  

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not quite clear what you need from us. Can you show us the code you've tried - even if it's not working? or some Pseudo-code that shows us what you think it should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information that you have supplied, a suggestion would be:

```
$style = $_GET['dowhat'];
echo "<td class='{$style}'>...</td>
```

The define the necessary CSS.